# What is the Solaris equivalent of chage -d?

Tags: solaris, accounts

I have been looking through the Solaris man pages: usermod, passwd and haven't had much luck.  I'm trying to find the equivalent of chage -d that we have used on Linux in the past.  This let's you set the date value of:

```
root@host:~# passwd -s someuser  
someuser  PS    02/08/17     0    10
```

the **02/08/17** date is what I'm trying to change.  I can do this in Linux with the following(to change the date to 10 days into the future):

```
 /usr/bin/chage -M 10 -d $(date +%F)
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris doesn't provide chage, but you can easily set the max number of days a password will be good for by using -x:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/passwd-1.html#scrolltoc

I believe 10 days from now would be:

`passwd -x 10 someuser`